# How to compress only uncompressed files?

Tags: linux, bash

I came up with the following command to brotli compress all files in a directory:

```sh
find "$PROJ_DIR/services/webpack/dist/" -type f -size +1000c -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(css|html|js|xml|svg)' -exec brotli -f -q 10 {} \+
```

But I'd like to only run it on files that don't have a corresponding `.br` file. Is there a nice way to do this? May be some way to get `find` to not return files that have this counterpart? Or if not, a quick way to file them out?

---

For example, given:

```
- foo.js
- foo.js.br
- bar.js
- charlie.css
- charlie.css.br
```

I only want to find `bar.js` because it doesn't have a matching `.br` file.

Comment: You're already using a regex.  Just modify it, to *exclude* files ending in "\.br$"

Comment: The regex isn't picking up the `.br` files. I want to find `.js` files without a matching `.js.br` file.

Comment: Loop thru the list of files, cache the previous row and compare. If no match, print previous and cache current. If match, reset. You may need to refine the states to make the logic work. I would throw this job to a higher level language with native dictionary data structure.

Comment: @BingWang I think you're over engineering this. Should be 3 or 4 lines of bash as Shawn has demonstrated

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the files returned by find and test to see if a compressed version already exists in the loop.

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    [[ $file -nt ${file}.br ]] && brotli -f -q 10 "$file"
done < <(find "$PROJ_DIR/services/webpack/dist/" -type f -size +1000c -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(css|html|js|xml|svg)' -print0)
```

(`file1 -nt file2` is true if the first file has a newer modification time than the second (or exists when the second one doesn't); seems useful to recompress in that case in case the contents changed since the last time it was compressed)

Comment: Wasn't me for the record. This looks good but I think we're losing some parallelization since we're only passing in one file to brotli at a time now. I can probably just push it into an array or something tho.

Comment: Can it compress multiple files at once in a single invocation, or does it compress them one at a time?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. Might have to run some tests... OK, ran some tests. `find ... -print0 | xargs -P8 -0 -n1 -- brotli -f -q 10` reduces the time from ~33s to ~11s so I guess it wasn't parallelized at all. That's a much bigger gain than I was expecting!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

```sh
uncompressed_files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    [[ $file -nt ${file}.br ]] && uncompressed_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "$PROJ_DIR/services/webpack/dist/" -type f -size +1000c -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(css|html|js|xml|svg)' -print0)
if [[ ${#uncompressed_files[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    printf "%s\0" "${uncompressed_files[@]}" | xargs -0 -n1 -t -P"$(nproc)" -- brotli -f -q 10 -n
fi
```

It expands on [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72253622/65387) by pushing the uncompressed files into an array so that I can compress them in parallel via `xargs`.